# Why is a conjugate transpose of $|+\rangle$ a vector $1/\sqrt{2} (\langle0| + \langle1|)$?

Tags: quantum-state

My understanding of the inner product is that it multiplies a vector by the conjugate transpose, but I don't understand why the conjugate transpose of $|+\rangle$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\langle0| + \langle1|)$.

Comment: What do you think the conjugate transpose should be? The conjugate transpose of $|0\rangle$ is $\langle0|$ and the conjugate transpose of $|1\rangle$ is $\langle1|$. So it follows that the conjugate transpose of $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ is  $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}(\langle0| + \langle1|)$.

Comment: why is |+> =  1/(√2) * (|0⟩+|1⟩) exactly?

Comment: It's a definition.

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to understand.  Why is it defined that way?  I guess I don't know what I don't know here.

Comment: It's a convention. Anytime you see $|+\rangle$ it means $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2) }(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex conjugation flips the sign of the imaginary part of a complex number. Transposition exchanges the row and column co-ordinates of a value in a matrix. A vector can be thought of as a matrix with 1 column and a certain amount of rows. The conjugation of this takes it to it's row form, which for a vector $|\psi\rangle$, becomes $\langle\psi|$.

Now you have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+|1\rangle$.$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is real, so complex conjugation does nothing. However, $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ become $\langle0|+\langle1|$.

So overall, you get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\langle0|+\langle1|)$